# PyMongo $inc having issues

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When trying to use $inc I get a Syntax error stating that $set is wrong. My query is as follow:

```
mongo_db.campaign.update({'_id': str(campaign_id)}, { $inc: { 'item': 1 } }):
```

I've looked at the mongo documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/) and other examples on SO but I can't find what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$inc` isn't a valid Python identifier. You should pass it as a string, like everything else:

```
mongo_db.campaign.update({'_id': str(campaign_id)}, {'$inc': {'item': 1}})
```

The MongoDB docs you linked are the general MongoDB documentation, not PyMongo-specific; you can't copy/paste them literally and expect things to work.

Comment: I should also add that when using '$inc' I was required to use int() around the number I wanted it to increment by:

{'$inc': {'item': int(1)}})

Comment: can we make this call on a collection?

Answer (score -4):

```
pymongo == 2.7 
campaign_id = bson.ObjectId(campaign_id)
mongo_db.campaign.update({'_id': campaign_id}, {'$inc': {'item': 1}})
```