# Find value and add to same value in the same statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

I am using two statements in `pymongo` to first find a value, add to that value, and then update the document. So say I get the original value with:

```
orig_item = list(db.collection.find({"id": 1}))[0]['A']
```

Then I need to add a new value to the original and update the document, again:

```
plus_item = orig_item + 5
db.collection.update_one({"id"   : 1},
                         {"$set" : {"A" : plus_item}})
```

So my question is, is there a more efficient way of doing this? Like in the same statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update_one({"id"   : 1},
                         {"$inc" : {"A" : 5}})
```

Ref: [PyMongo $inc having issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054494/pymongo-inc-having-issues)

Answer (score 1):

As said by @John Zwinck
you can use `$inc` to increment the value. you can use it in  `findOneAndUpdate()` to update the first occurrence [refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate)
or you can also use `findAndModify()` [refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) if you want to update multiple values. so your code will be

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({"id":1},{ $inc : {"A" : 5}})
```

[refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#inc) to know how `inc` operator works.