# How Do I Increment My View Counter in Flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

**Summary and Background of What I'm Doing:**

**I'm creating an app** which allows you to add and store recipes and I would like to be able to organise my recipe list using the numbers of views each recipe receives. I should explain that I have a list of recipes and if you click on the title of one of the recipes in that list, it will bring you to a new page and display that recipe. This way I can organise my app into three categories of lists (Breakfast, Lunch, and Dinner).

I'm using **MongoDB** to host my key/value pairs **("views":0)** and **I want to be able to increment the value of "views" by +1** each time someone refreshes the page. I'll provide my code below, but I think my problem is that I can't seem to make the value increment in my HTML or in MongoDB. Let me explain: I'm almost certain that my routing code is correct. I've watched many tutorials on **the appropriate way to $inc a value in MongoDB**, but I believe I'm missing something from my HTML to properly correspond to that code and I'm not sure what it is.

**When I run this code** it still works and there's no error warning, but when I get to any recipe page, the view counter doesn't change when I refresh that page. It just remains at 0.

I should also say that I have two separate routes which I think relate to each other in this case: I have a "view_recipe" route which shows the page of the recipe, and I have a "view_count" route which functions to count views. I'll provide both of these below along with my HTML for everyone to inspect.

**What I've Tried So Far:**

For my recipe app I've followed Youtube tutorials on how to $inc my key/value, however it's the information that I need to provide to my HTML which I'm unsure of. Based on other examples, my corresponding view information in HTML is this:

```
<a href="{{url_for('view_recipe', recipe_id=recipe._id)}}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn_small blue">{{recipe.views})</a>
```

I've provided a url_for the route and made what I thought was the relevant recipe_id=recipe._id like I saw in other examples I've used to target the id.

**My Code:**

Here are my routes for both **"view_recipe"** and **"view_count"**:

```
@app.route('/view_recipe/<recipe_id>')
def view_recipe(recipe_id):
    the_recipe =  mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)})
    return render_template('view_recipe.html', recipe=the_recipe)

@app.route('/view_count/<recipe_id>')
def view_count(recipe_id):
    mongo.db.recipes
    recipes.update({'_id': str(recipe_id)}, {'$inc': {'views': int(1)}})
    return url_for('view_recipe.html')
```

and here's the section for the view count that I provided in my **"view_recipe.html"** where I place **{{recipe.view}}**

```
<a href="{{url_for('view_recipe', recipe_id=recipe._id)}}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn_small blue">{{recipe.views})</a>
```

**What Happens When I Run this Code vs What I expect to Happen:**

The code runs, however it doesn't increment like I expect it to. The counter just stays at 0 and doesn't go up when I refresh the page. My hope is that once the page is refreshed, the value of the counter will, increment and be displayed in both the browser and update in my MongoDb collection.

**Just in case...**

If you need any more information or if I haven't been clear enough or explain this well, please let me know and I'll fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: You  have `view_count` view but you have no way of reaching it. You should likely increment the counter in the `view_recipe` view directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I'm wording it wrong but this is what I tried:

    @app.route('/view_recipe/<recipe_id>')
     def view_recipe(recipe_id):
        the_recipe =  mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)}, 
        {'$inc': {'views': int(1)}})
        return render_template('view_recipe.html', recipe=the_recipe)

and I got this error:

Unsupported projection option: $inc: { views: 1 }

Comment: Also, apologies, I'm unsure of how to format code in the comments. Sorry that's messy.

Comment: I am not familiar with MongoDB, but you likely cannot increment the counter and find the recipe in one query. Try to use two instruction: `the_recipe =  mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)})` and then `mongo.db.recipes.update({'_id': str(recipe_id)}, {'$inc': {'views': int(1)}})`.

Comment: You should also be consistent and use `ObjectId(recipe_id)` or `str(recipe_id)` in both case.

Comment: I tried this:

@app.route('/view_recipe/<recipe_id>')
def view_recipe(recipe_id):
    the_recipe =  mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": str(recipe_id)})
    mongo.db.recipes.update({"_id": str(recipe_id)}, {'$inc': {'views': int(1)}})
    return render_template('view_recipe.html', recipe=the_recipe, view=views)

and got a bracket error that I don't see:

TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'

Comment: I think you're right though, I can't increment and find the recipe in a single query.

Comment: Try checking the result of `recipes.update()` in your `view_count` method. If the `_id` doesn't match this command will run successfully (i.e. without error) but update 0 documents. Are you using the default ObjectIDs for `_id` or a string? The current `_id` value is being passed as a string type so it won't match an ObjectID.

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask, but could you show me what that looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Might need some tweaking for the Mongo DB stuff, but why not just have the `view_count` function without the route, as this shouldn't need to be called via a URL.  Instead call it directly within the `view_recipe` function.

```
@app.route('/view_recipe/<int:recipe_id>')
def view_recipe(recipe_id):
    the_recipe =  mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": recipe_id})
    view_count(recipe_id) # call the other function here.
    return render_template('view_recipe.html', recipe=the_recipe)

def view_count(recipe_id):
    recipes = mongo.db.recipes
    recipes.update({'_id': recipe_id}, {'$inc': {'views': 1}})
    return True
```

- In the route the argument should be `<int:recipe_id>` which ensures the user input is an integer.
- The second function no longer needs to return `render_template` so instead returns True.
- You can't just call `mongo.db.recipes` in the view function.  I've changed this so you set `receipes` to this, and then access `receipes.update`.  This would be the same as calling `mongo.db.recipes.update()`

### EDIT

I'm assuming you're using `pymongo`.  Note the changes above.

I was so curious I fired up a mongo DB test box and tried this.  I've tested and uploaded [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/191bafe82bdc54ec0379c4f05caf05b6) with a `shell.py` file that shows my initial config, and a bare-bones flask app which imports `db.py` to demonstrate this.

I think you're issue was that [ObjectID()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#description) actually does something unrelated.  You should just need to pass the `recipe_id` as my code demonstrates.  I can then test with a few executions of `curl http://localhost:5000/1` and watch the dev server output which increments the count each time:

```
Db script:  {'_id': 1, 'text': 'TEST', 'counter': 5}
Flask says:  {'_id': 1, 'text': 'TEST', 'counter': 6}
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2018 01:22:21] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Flask says:  {'_id': 1, 'text': 'TEST', 'counter': 7}
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2018 01:22:22] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Flask says:  {'_id': 1, 'text': 'TEST', 'counter': 8}
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2018 01:22:22] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: That looks like it would work beautifully, and you're right, it makes more sense to put both functions in one route. However on my end I'm getting this error when I try that:

'function' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: Erm,  is the <int:recipe_id> necessary? The MongoDB value is set as an integer and it's a page refresh, so I don't know how it could be interpreted any other way. Also, we've specified the value as int(1) in the function. Not to be contrary, I'm still learning myself, but that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Have a look at [variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules) which provides more info on the latter. EDIT: this is actually verifying input from the user which could be anything.

Comment: Oh, fairness enough. I didn't know that. I am getting another error though with this code:

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ObjectId'

Comment: Try swapping that line out for: `recipes.update({'_id': ObjectId(recipe_id)}, {'$inc': {'views': 1}})` as I've edited my answer, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054663/2052575)

Comment: I get this error now:

"int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ObjectId'"

I'm really sorry.

Comment: This is quite annoying and I hope you can get to the bottom of it.  Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with the mongodb part.  The last error in your comment would suggest that `ObjectId(recipe_id)` should be swapped for `recipe_id` or `int(recipe_id)` although the ObjectID notation appears to have worked in the other function?  A good debug step might be to try replacing this with a straight integer rather than trying to dynamically load it: `{'_id': 1}` or `{'_id': '1'}` so that you're hard coding the ID of an exisitng record to narrow down the issue.  Good luck and please post your results!

Comment: Thanks all the same for your help. It's appreciated.

Comment: @MartinCurran Thanks for marking the answer accepted.  If you solved the one liner, please edit my answer with the correct mongodb syntax.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't. I must've up marked it by mistake. I apologise for that and didn't mean to. I'm still working on it.

Comment: I still get this error: "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ObjectId'". Would it help if I share my cloud9 workspace with you to take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185941/discussion-between-v25-and-martin-curran).